# Prepopulate fields in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, javascript, html

I want to display First name and last name in Name Text field, I have

> FirstName :
>
> LastName  :
>
> Name      :

When user enters FirstName(Micky),Lastname(Mouse)-- Name--should populate with Firstname and lastName (Micky mouse) automatically.

Comment: Hi @sainath, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Create a Formula field with data type Text.

formula `FirstName + LastName`

and refer this Formula field in your visualforce page.

Comment: i want that functionality in HTML and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would strongly suggest you look at this [Visualforce](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/visualforce_fundamentals) Trailhead module. Your question should include what you have tried so far and if you cannot create the basic markup, continue to work through Salesforce Trailhead modules on Visualforce.

The page is using the `Contact` `standardController`.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
```

As for the markup needed, here is an extremely basic `form` to accept two values, `FirstName` and `LastName`, and then generate a concatenated string from controlled JavaScript.

```
<apex:form id="f">
    <apex:outputText value="FirstName:"/>
    <apex:inputText value="{!Contact.FirstName}" id="fname" onchange="setVal();"/>
    <br/>
    <apex:outputText value="LastName:"/>
    <apex:inputText value="{!Contact.LastName}" id="lname" onchange="setVal();"/>
    <br/>
    Name: 
    <apex:outputText id="name" />
</apex:form>
```

To have your inputText values controlled by some JS, you will need to include a short script.

```
<script>
    function setVal(){
        var fname = document.getElementById('{!$Component.f.fname}').value;
        var lname = document.getElementById('{!$Component.f.lname}').value;
        document.getElementById('{!$Component.f.name}').innerHTML = ' ' + fname + ' ' + lname;
    }
</script>
```

Here we can see the `form id(f)` is being used to access the First and Last name values and further to set the Name `outputText` value.